# How to create Global Variable in Autosys?

Tags: autosys

Do I need to create global variable before I can run the Autosys job below? If so how do i create one? I inherited some legacy code from someone and now I'm pulling my hair trying to figure out how to do that.

```
insert_job: AUTOSYS_TEST_VARIABLE   job_type: c
command: sendevent -E SET_GLOBAL -G TEST_VARIABLE=TRUE
machine: MACHINE_ALIAS
owner: testowner
permission: gx,mx
description: set global variable
alarm_if_fail: 1
profile:/home/test/dbreplication.env
timezone: US/Eastern
```

Comment: What is your intention of the global variable? In your example, you are setting "TEST_VARIABLE" equal to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sendevent -E SET_GLOBAL -G TEST_VARIABLE=TRUE defines and set the TEST_VARIABLE. The reason it wasn't working for me was because I need to have specific pattern of variable name for my application.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using global variables in Autosys is to use them in another job.

For example, you can use `TEST_VARIABLE` in another job.

Here is an example:

```
insert_job: IB_ITOps_Opt_1008_TEST_VARIABLE_OUTPUT 
condition: $${TEST_VARIABLE}
job_type: c
machine: MACHINE_ALIAS
```

In this job, the condition is based on your variable you set in the other job, using the `sendevent -E SET_GLOBAL -G`

Comment: thank you for answering the question. So does it mean that I don't have to declare it or create a variable ?
sendevent -E SET_GLOBAL -G TestToday=TRUE
Will this create TEST_GLOBAL and set it to TRUE ?